# Word for person with lots of energy

Tags: meaning, verbs

What do you call someone who has lots of energy and always in good mood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*vivacious*, *vibrant*, *vital*, *lively*, *energetic*, *enthusiastic*, *merry*.

And check those for more synonyms and near synonyms...

Comment: I'd call such a person *sickening*.

Comment: My nine-year-old grandson has the energy part, but he's not always in a good mood.